# R using a lookup to replace values in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector, sapply

Say I have a matrix (dates are col and row names)

```
B=matrix(rep(1,16),ncol=4,nrow=4)
rownames(B) = c("2012-08-06","2012-08-13","2012-08-20","2012-08-27")
colnames(B) = c("2012-08-06","2012-08-13","2012-08-20","2012-08-27")

    2012-08-06  2012-08-13  2012-08-20  2012-08-27
2012-08-06  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2012-08-13  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2012-08-20  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2012-08-27  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

and a lookup:

```
lookup = c("2012-08-13","2012-08-20")
```

Right now I have loop that looks through each value of lookup, and replaces the numbers in the matrix which have the colname or row name of that date
i.e. I have some logic that takes each value of lookup
and does a vector replace
i.e. vector[somelogic,somelogic] = new value
Here is a simplified example:

```
for(i in lookup){
B[rownames(B) < i, colnames(B) > i] = 2
B[rownames(B) > i, colnames(B) == i] = 5
}
```

is there a way to do this with sapply or something like that?

Comment: Can you provide the loop that you are currently using or at least the desired output for the sample data?

Comment: I have added the example

Comment: Your example remains incomplete because you can't use `<` and `>` on character strings and each iteration of your loop does the same thing. I imagine you're looking for something involving `which(rownames(b) == lookup[i])`, etc. but it's unclear from the current information.

Comment: it works on mine, but happy for it to be casted as.Date

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a `sapply` solution if the loop works as intended.

Converting to `date`

```
 rB <- as.Date(rownames(B))
 cB <- as.Date(colnames(B))
 lookup <- as.Date(lookup)

 lst1 <- lapply(lookup, function(i) {
  B[rB < i, cB > i] <- 2
  B[rB > i, cB == i] <- 5
  B
  })

  Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(x!=1 & y==1, x,y), lst1)
  #               2012-08-06 2012-08-13 2012-08-20 2012-08-27
  # 2012-08-06          1          1          2          2
  # 2012-08-13          1          1          1          2
  # 2012-08-20          1          5          1          1
  # 2012-08-27          1          5          5          1
```

Comment: Hello, your output creates a new object though, I want to replace the values in matrix B

Comment: @shecode. I think these kind of problems are better solved using `for()` loop.

Comment: I have solved it via a for() loop. It is too slow. that is my concern